Keras MultiHeadAttention and padding mask warnings
I'm creating a transformer model with tensorflow/keras. First time using tensorflow.
I'm using a MultiHeadAttention-layer. My input is zero-padded, and has a mask. I get warnings about the mask being discarded. But it seems like the mask is indeed used.
This is a simple piece of code to reproduce it:
import tensorflow as tf

values = tf.expand_dims([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0], 0)
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(64, 512, mask_zero=True)(values)
attn = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=1, key_dim=512)
output, attention_scores = attn(query=x, key=x, value=x, return_attention_scores=True)

print(attention_scores)

Output:
tf.Tensor(
[[[[0.3333333  0.3333318  0.33333483 0.         0.         0.        ]
   [0.33333272 0.3333335  0.33333382 0.         0.         0.        ]
   [0.33333284 0.3333336  0.33333352 0.         0.         0.        ]
   [0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667]
   [0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667]
   [0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667 0.16666667]]]], shape=(1, 1, 6, 6), dtype=float32)

UserWarning: Layer 'query' (of type EinsumDense) was passed an input with a mask attached to it. However, this layer does not support masking and will therefore destroy the mask information. Downstream layers will not see the mask.
UserWarning: Layer 'key' (of type EinsumDense) was passed an input with a mask attached to it. However, this layer does not support masking and will therefore destroy the mask information. Downstream layers will not see the mask.
UserWarning: Layer 'value' (of type EinsumDense) was passed an input with a mask attached to it. However, this layer does not support masking and will therefore destroy the mask information. Downstream layers will not see the mask.

From TF 2.10.0 release notes:
Improved masking support for tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention.

    Implicit masks for query, key and value inputs will automatically be used to compute a correct attention mask for the layer. These padding masks will be combined with any attention_mask passed in directly when calling the layer. This can be used with tf.keras.layers.Embedding with mask_zero=True to automatically infer a correct padding mask.
    Added a use_causal_mask call time arugment to the layer. Passing use_causal_mask=True will compute a causal attention mask, and optionally combine it with any attention_mask passed in directly when calling the layer.

So my understanding is that tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention supports this mask, and it looks like it does. But I still get these warnings. Is it safe to ignore the warnings? And if so, is there a good way to suppress just these warnings?

In TensorFlow 2.15, the MultiHeadAttention layer supports padding masks and it can be done using the attention_mask argument. However, later versions (2.16+) might have issues with mask propagation from embeddings to attention layer. In such cases, these warnings can be safely ignored as  they just notify you that the mask handling isn't fully explicit at the MultiHeadAttention layer level and they do not impact the code's functionality.
